# Gradle Managed Devices - ChromeCustomTab not working

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-managed-device

I'm starting to use this [`Gradle Managed Devices`](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices) feature and I'm facing some problems when running my `Espresso` tests.

I setup the device as follows :

```
testOptions {
            animationsDisabled = true
            managedDevices {
                devices {
                    maybeCreate<ManagedVirtualDevice>("pixel2api30").apply {
                        device = "Pixel 2"
                        apiLevel = 30
                        systemImageSource = "google-atd"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And then I have an `Activity` that when I press a `Button` it opens either a `ChromeCustomTab` or a `WebView`, the thing is that in my device, emulator (locally) it works but when I try to run them in `GMD` it doesn't and throws me this error.

```
es.MyTest > testName[pixel2api30] FAILED 
        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.example.es/... (has extras) }
                at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
```

And what I'm doing is this :

```
Intents.init()
    try {
        val expectedIntent = allOf(
            hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW),
            anyOf(
                hasPackage("com.android.chrome"),
                hasPackage("com.android.webview")
            ),
            hasData(Uri.parse(url)),
        )
        //on click to the button to open the `ChromeCustomTab`
        intended(expectedIntent)
    } finally {
        Intents.release()
    }
```

I also have this for opening a `WebView` and it works though

```
Intents.init()
    try {
        //click to the button
        intended(
            allOf(
                hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW),
                hasData(Uri.parse(url)),
            ),
        )
    } finally {
        Intents.release()
    }
```

Also what I saw is that some test are too fast and makes my `MockWebServer` and my `Dispatcher` to fail sometimes so I had to add a small wait to the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking the documentation and I found this :

> Which source the system image should come from. Either "google", "google-atd", "aosp", or "aosp-atd". You can also specify an explicit source such as "google_apis_playstore".

I did not ready the part that I could add the `google_apis_playstore` that one comes with `Google Chrome App` that was what I need, however it did not fix the problem since using this command

```
./gradlew :features-myFeature:pixel2api30ReleaseAndroidTest --enable-display -Pandroid.testoptions.manageddevices.emulator.gpu=swiftshader_indirect
```

was throwing a `TimeOutException`

> Failed to execute adb command.
> Command: /Users/* -H localhost -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r -t /Users/*-release-androidTest.apk
> Timeout: 120
> Command timed out: 120
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Command timed out: 120
> at com.google.testing.platform.lib.process.SubprocessImpl$waitFor$1.invokeSuspend(SubprocessImpl.kt:286)

I thought it was going to fix the issue since the `--enable-display` was launching the emulator and in there I was able to see the `Google Chrome App` installed.

So what I did instead is to change the way I was *asserting* the `openWebView()` and I'm doing it like this

```
fun assertOpenWebView(url: String, action: () -> Unit) {
    Intents.init()
    try {
        val expectedIntent = allOf(
            hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW),
            hasData(Uri.parse(url)),
        )
        intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null))
        action.invoke()
        intended(allOf(expectedIntent))
    } finally {
        Intents.release()
    }
}
```

I want to ensure that my code at least does the action of try to open a web view or something similar, and it makes the test pass from now, but I'd like to know if I can make it work like it was before using the `google_apis_playstore` system image.